# Internet is extremely slow on Ubuntu with Realtek 8168 (rev 09)

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

I was using Windows 10 and decided to install Ubuntu, my internet works extremly slow. On Windows 10 it worked perfectly fine.
edit:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard [1043:8505]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: What is your "internet"? Wired, wireless or what?

Comment: Wired, model of router huawei hg530

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Pilot6, I've just done it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

and reboot.

This will install another driver. It should work better.

Comment: I tried and got some kind of error, here is 'log' http://pastebin.com/LG9EbHjW

Comment: At the end I think I installed it, reboted but it works pretty simillar..

Comment: One thing that might help, even though it's not driver related, is to change DNS settings. I've got my DNS set to Google DNS 8.8.8.8 as primary, and 8.8.4.4 as secondary. It's a noticeable improvement as far as loading time for webpages.

Comment: @LukeFlip And what is in that `make.log`?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think `r8168-dkms` compiles. Use solution from [here](https://amk1.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/realtek-8168-module-issue/), this one works fine, although you can not upgrade kernel without having to recompile. Somehow, it only worked for me if I compiled as root:

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
wget http://12244.wpc.azureedge.net/8012244/drivers/rtdrivers/cn/nic/0002-r8168-8.040.00.tar.bz2
sha256sum 0002-r8168-8.040.00.tar.bz2 
 --> da0444fcd7aabb7762310cdf2047fd0aeb7a9ed97a3d6b80d62a0fc71e0730bf  0002-r8168-8.040.00.tar.bz2
tar -xjf 0002-r8168-8.040.00.tar.bz2 
cd r8168-8.040.00/
sudo make
sudo make install
```

then you need to blacklist r8169, cross fingers and reboot